# Script batch copy from subfolder to main folder filtering extension

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have this schema

SOURCE

```
FOLDER_A

---FOLDERA1

------file1.abc

------file2.abc

------file2.txt

---FOLDERB1

------file3.abc

------file4.abc

------file.txt
```

I want to create a batch script which copies in a new folder only

DESTINATION

```
FOLDER_A1

---file1.abc

---file2.abc

FOLDERB1

---file3.abc

---file4.abc
```

putting in the destination only the second level (`FOLDER_A` should be deleted) and filtering only files with `.abc` extension

I wrote this code

```bat
@echo off

set SOURCE_DIR=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SCRIPT\source2 
set DEST_DIR=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\SCRIPT\dest

pause
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a In ('dir /ad/b %SOURCE_DIR% ') do (
    set current_folder=%SOURCE_DIR%\%%a\

    mkdir "dest\%%a"

    for /r  %SOURCE_DIR% %%f in (*.abc) do (
    @copy "%%f" "dest\%%a"
)   
    pause
)
@pause
```

The problem is that in the destination I have the folder with the right name but inside of them everytime the 4 files `file1.abc`, `file2.abc`, `file3.abc` and `file4.abc`.

The goal is to have inside the first folder only `file1.abc` and `file2.abc`, and in the second folder `file3.abc` and `file4.abc`.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using batchfiles and for-loops for this? Both `xcopy` and `robocopy` commands have exclusion features. Just type `xcopy /?` and `robocopy /?` for more information, and on the internet, you might find plenty of examples on how to do this.

**Edit after first comment**

It's indeed not that simple to work with the `/Exclude` switch, as you can see in following example:

```
C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A>echo .txt>patterns.txt 
  // in this file, I mention that filenames, containing .txt, should not be copied

C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A>xcopy /F /S C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\*.* C:\Temp_Folder\Destination\ /Exclude:C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\patterns.txt 
  // here I refer to the file, containing the patterns, not to copy
C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\FolderA1\file1.abc -> C:\Temp_Folder\Destination\FolderA1\file1.abc
C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\FolderA1\file2.abc -> C:\Temp_Folder\Destination\FolderA1\file2.abc
C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\FolderB1\file3.abc -> C:\Temp_Folder\Destination\FolderB1\file3.abc
C:\Temp_Folder\Folder_A\FolderB1\file4.abc -> C:\Temp_Folder\Destination\FolderB1\file4.abc
4 File(s) copied
```

Comment: exactly, it copy all the 4 files, but I want that copy 2 files in the first folder and 2 in the second

Comment: @PaoloDavid: as you can see, files are copied from FolderA1 into destination FolderA1 and from FolderB1 into destination FolderB1. That was the intention, right?